# Android - what is the most reliable way to determine which country the user is in

Tags: android

I am currently looking at doing something like this:

```
    TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (teleMgr != null)
    {
       String countryISOCode = teleMgr.getSimCountryIso();
       ...
```

But I do not know whether all countries comply with this and the getSimCountryIso(); function would work for all phones.  Is this reliabl 100% or 99% ...or is another way to tell where the user is from more reliable?

Thanks!

Comment: What if the user is out of his country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most accurate way would be to first, get the `LocationManager`. Then, call `LocationManager.getLastKnownPosition`. Then, create a GeoCoder and call `GeoCoder.getFromLocation`. Do this is a separate thread!! This will give you a list of `Address` objects. Call `Address.getCountryName` and you got it.

Keep in mind that the last known position can be a bit stale, so if the user just crossed the border, you may not know about it for a while.

The SIM card method you currently use will return an incorrect country if the user is on International Roaming.

Another method would be to use the user Locale:

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry();
```

However, this will return a country based on the language preferences, and won't be accurate for places which don't have a locale in Android (for example, a user in Switzerland would probably have the language set to German or French, resulting in an incorrect country.

Comment: thank you - I am ok with the international roaming not being correct.  I was just concerned whether the method I posted would be reliable if the person is in their country.  Or will many potentially have that field not set?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that every SIM card will have that field set. However, if it isn't set, `TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()` will definitely work if the user is connected to a network, and could be used as a fallback.